# UPDATE PDO, AJAX, PHP Orientado A Objeto

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo

Eu tenho a seguinte função dentro da minha classe

```
public function update(){

                try{

                    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE Tabela SET Dado1 = :Dado1, Dado2 = :Dado2, Dado3 = :Dado3 WHERE DadoId = :DadoId");
                    $stmt->bindParam(':Dado1', $Dado1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':Dado2', $Dado2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':Dado3', $Dado3, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $stmt->execute();

                    if ($stmt > 0)
                    {

                        header ( "location:retorno.php" );

                    }

                    return $stmt;

                }catch (PDOStatement $excption){

                    header("Location: ./error.php?err=Unable to insert");
                    echo 'Erro: '.$exception->getMessage();         
                    return null; 

                } 
 }
```

E geralmente eu faço um método post para enviar ele:

```
$up = new Classe();

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

    if(isset($_POST['btn-update']))
    {
        $stDado1= strip_tags($_POST['stn-Dado1']);
        $stDado2 = strip_tags($_POST['stn-Dado2']);     
        $stDado3 = strip_tags($_POST['stn-Dado3']);
        $sendInsert = $up->update($stDado1, $stDado2, $stDado3);
    }

    exit();
}
```

Só que eu tenho um problema, meu **Dado3** é um TAG `<div>`, que recebe um Texto, eu recebe através do JQuery um `.html()`, porque o que foi gravado no banco é um código HTML.

```
<form method="POST">
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Dado 1</label>                                                            
        <input class="form-control" name="dado1" type="text" >
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label>Dado 2</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="dado2" type="text">                                                       
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Dado 3</label>
        <hr>
        <div name="dado3" contentEditable="false">                                                                
        </div>
    </div>
<hr>
<a class="btn btn-warning edit">Editar</a>
<a class="btn btn-warning cancel">Cancelar</a>
<button type="submit" name="btn-update" class="btn btn-danger ">Salvar</button>

</form>
```

Tem algum jeito de eu enviar esse `<div name="dado3" contentEditable="false"></div>`, para o banco via ajax ou algum outro método?

Comment: Sim é possível, apenas tags do form tem atributo `name`, seu div deve ter um `id`, pegue ele com jquery e envia via ajax para o php, talvez seja necessário um tratemento no html.

Comment: @rray meu problema é como passar um ajax orientado a objeto, você tem alguma documentação boa sobre isso, estou procurando bastante no google, mas realmente não está entrando na minha cabeça isso.